# How do I get the corresponding name of a max value (Tableau)

Tags: tableau-api

In Tableau, I have a table with 3 columns: Name, Category, and Number of Ratings

I have grouped my table by category and want to return the name of the row with the max number of ratings. If I do MAX([Number of Ratings]) it returns the maximum numerical value of ratings but I also require the string value of the Name column

For example:

Original Data

| Name | Category | Number of Ratings |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | Cat 1 | 5 |
| Second | Cat 1 | 1 |
| Third | Cat 1 | 3 |
| Fourth | Cat 2 | 10 |
| Fifth | Cat 2 | 2 |

Aggregated Data:

| Category | Number of Items | Max Number of Ratings |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | 10 |

I need a column that would return 'First' for Row 1 and 'Fourth' for Row 2 of Aggregated Data

Edit: Just to be clear, this aggregated table is what I already have created. What I need help on is creating the column that returns 'First' for Row 1 and 'Fourth' for Row 2

Answer (score 0):

In order to get what you're looking for, you just have to drag and drop your fields playing around with the aggregation measure.

You should get something like the following, in a matter of few clicks.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear enough. I have already managed to get to this point; the second table in my original post is what I already manipulated. What I need is to figure out the corresponding name that is attached to the MAX(Number of Ratings) and make an additional column with that information. So the third column (which is what I am unsure on how to set up) is the one that would have 'First' and 'Fourth' as its two data entries